# Get a text from HTML using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I am a beginner in JavaScript.
I'm trying to understand how can I work with DOM in js...

I would like to get a text from some website, from every DIV no matter how complex the structure is.
If I run my code below it will give me the text but:
patern div give me his text and text from child div... then child div give me his text...
So a get a lot of repeated text.

```
var items = document.body.getElementsByTagName('*');
for(var i=0; i<items.length; i++)
{
  document.write(items[i].textContent);
}
```

It's important to me to know the node of current text So I can't use this because I get the text but I don't know the nodes of text:

```
var body = document.body, textContent = 'textContent' in body ? body.textContent : body.innerText;
document.write(textContent);
```

I know the resolution is jQuery., but I'm trying to understand how to do this in JS.

Comment: Take a look at this post .. I think its a bit similar to what you want to achieve.. http://www.webmasterworld.com/javascript/3607091.htm?highlight=msg3607357

Answer (score 0):

You can try getting all the matching elements using the jQuery .get() function.

Example:

```
var elements = [];
elements = $('div').get();
```

Once you have all the elements you can then grab the text, if any from each element and store it in another array like so:

```
var textStrings = [];
var len = elements.length;
for(var a = 0; a < len; a++)
    textStrings[a] = elements[a].text();
```

The second code block will run through the first array of elements and pull the text from each one, saving it in a second array called textStrings. The 'len' variable is used so to optimize the javascript code and prevent the browser from evaluating 'elements.length' each time through the loop.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The usual `textContent` or `innerHTML` approach fails in this situation, as the `.innerHTML` contains the HTML of the child nodes.

But there is another property you can use: `childNodes`. This list does not only contain the child *elements*, but all child *nodes*, including *text nodes*:

```
var items = document.body.getElementsByTagName('*');
for(var i=0; i<items.length; i++)
{
  var currItem = items[i];
  for(var j = 0; j < currItem.childNodes.length; ++j)
  {
    if(currItem.childNodes[j].nodeName === "#text")
    {
      // the current child node is a text node
      document.write(items[i].textContent);
    }
  }
}
```

Since every node has a unique position in the DOM this will ensure that every node is written exactly once.

#### References:

- W3C: DOM Level 3 (Official documents)

  - [Node.nodeName](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/core.html#ID-F68D095)
  - [Node.childNodes](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/core.html#ID-1451460987)
- Mozilla Developer Network (Easier to understand)

  - [Node.nodeName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Node.nodeName)
  - [Node.childNodes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Node.childNodes)